# PostgreSQL Generate Series that displays rolling trailing 12 months

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I'm attempting to create a Generate Series that displays the trailing 12 months based on the current date. Currently, I'm just getting the current month displayed 12 times.

```
select date_trunc('month',current_date)::date as month
from generate_series(
  date_trunc('month', current_date)::date - interval '11 months',current_date, '1 month')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your select overrides the series returned.  So all you get is 12 instances (the number of rows returned from the series) of `date_trunc('month',current_date)::date`, which is always the current month of course.

You probably want this:

```
select *
from generate_series(
    date_trunc('month', current_date)::date - interval '11 months',current_date, '1 month')
```

Or with an alias:

```
select dMonths
from generate_series(
    date_trunc('month', current_date)::date - interval '11 months',current_date, '1 month') dMonths
```